# Cannot load stylesheet expressJs while trying to get error pages

Tags: node.js, express

I'm stuck in trying to get error pages rendered with a template in my expressJs app.
While I try to write..

```
app.get('/*', pages.error_page);
```

..the app works fine but without any style! Removing that line everything comes back to normal.
Here's my simple function to load error page:

```
exports.errore_pagina = function (req, res){
res.render('errore', {title: 'Pagina errore'});
}
```

The app.get is in the bottom of the page just before:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Did anybody find the same issue?
Thanks a lot!
Francesco

Comment: Shouldnt you use `pages.errore_pagina`  instead of `pages.error_page`?

Comment: Your /* route is probably catching and handling the request for your CSS file. Do you have a line for static files? You should have a line like app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) somewhere in your code before other routes to handle CSS files.

Comment: @HectorCorrea you should make that a formal answer so the OP can accept it. If your static handler goes before app.router, then your error page route won't conflict with your static assets.

Answer (score 1):

I already had a line for handling static files:

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The issue was about the position! As suggested by @rdrey that line should be before the app.router! Thanks to @HectorCorrea too!